# Ordering seaborn heatmap xticks given certain values

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have this given data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Patch
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'C': np.random.choice([False, False, False, True], 100000),
                   'D': np.random.choice([False,True], 100000),
                   'B': np.random.choice([False,True, True], 100000),
                   'A': np.random.choice([False, False, True], 100000),
                   'F': np.random.choice([False,True, True, True], 100000)})
```

Where I plot this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 6))
cmap = sns.mpl_palette("Set2", 2)
sns.heatmap(data=df, cmap=cmap, cbar=False)
plt.xticks(rotation=90, fontsize=10)
plt.yticks(rotation=0, fontsize=10)

legend_handles = [Patch(color=cmap[True], label='Missing Value'),  # red
                  Patch(color=cmap[False], label='Non Missing Value')]  # blue-green
plt.legend(handles=legend_handles, ncol=2, bbox_to_anchor=[0.5, 1.02], loc='lower center', fontsize=8, handlelength=.8)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

I have been trying to order the x-axis from higher to lower (left to right) given the count of `True` values. So, the first position should have the highest amount of `True` values, the second position the second highest, and so on.

I was able to get the positions and their respective labels with:

```
x_axis = df.sum().rank(method="dense", ascending=False)
x_pos = x_axis.values.tolist()
x_labels = x_axis.index.tolist()
```

But  I'm struggling trying to put this in the plot and make it work, and also because I need to be sure that I'm not just changuing the position of the labels but also the position of the variables displayed in the plot (as I'm visualizing near 100 variables in the real dataframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract order then reindex:

```
orders = df.sum().sort_values(ascending=False).index

# change this:
sns.heatmap(data=df.reindex(orders, axis=1), cmap=cmap, cbar=False)
```

Output:

[image]